# Referring to something belonging to a goblin: is it "its" thing or "his" thing?

Tags: animals, grammatical-gender, possessive-determiners, pronominal-agreement

I'm writing tutorial for fantasy game with said goblin acting as an example. Now, I need to relate to the thing belonging to that goblin, let's say it's an apple. Is it *his* apple or *its* apple? Shall I treat mythological creature as a human or as an animal?

Comment: A lot of science fiction and fantasy writers insist on intelligence and emotions as to an entities position towards compassionate treatment. There are plenty of examples and counter-examples of good monsters and bad people. For fun, position these: Shrek, Smeedle, Yoda, Jabba, Mr. Bump, I-Robot, Chewbacca, Aslam, Dr. No

Comment: Animals still take *his* or *her*, not *its*, unless you simply do not know the gender.  An **animal** is an **animate**, and things with **animas** merit **animate** determiners and pronouns, not inanimate ones.  A male animal is a *him*, a female animal is a *her*.  Never call a mother an it!  An apple, however, is an *it*, because it is not animate. Neither is a rock.  But a mother dog, bitch though she be, is a *her* just as  a bull moose is a *him*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice depends on whether you are intending to treat the creature as a *person*, not a human or animal. For instance, *Charlotte's Web* anthropomorphises animals, using *his* or *hers* for ownership. On the other side of the coin, it was typical to refer to the belongings of slaves as *its*; even though they were human, they were not considered people.

Comment: Um, you still use *his* and *hers* with animates, provided their genders are known. It’s not like those are only for people. The vixen licked her lips. The stallion left a cloud of dust in his wake. A mother hen clucks her head off.  A doe hides her fawn in tall grass.  A billy-goat is sure on his feet. A bull will charge at anything waving at him, not just at red. A cow takes care of her new calf. etc etc etc

Answer (score 4):

If you have a **male** goblin, then speak of *his thing*; if a **female** goblin, of *her thing*.

Animals still take *his* or *her*, not *its*, unless you simply do not know the creature’s gender.

An **animal** is an **animate**, and things with **animas** merit **animate** determiners and pronouns, not inanimate ones.   A male animal is a *him*, a female animal is a *her*.  Never call a mother an *it*!  She will ***not*** be pleased.

An apple, however, is an *it*, because it is not animate. Neither is a rock. Feel free to refer to a rock as *it*; it won’t mind.

But a mother dog, bitch though she be, is a *her* just as much as a bull moose is a *him*.

Anyway, a goblin is not merely a creature, but a sentient.  We only use *it* for things without animas, and the fact that the goblin not only gibbers and shrieks but actually speaks, makes the goblin a sentient being.

Imagine a goblin family with a mommy and a daddy: you can’t call either of them *it*. It just doesn’t make sense that they are both *its*.  They’re *him* and *her*, obviously.

Only use *it* for inanimates.

Comment: If the goblin parents are the same gender, they wouldn't be *him* and *her*. Additionally, knowing the gender of something does not ***require*** you to use a gender when describing that thing. "The cow was in the field. It was chewing its cud." The usage of *it* vs *him or her* is strictly based on the level of empathy the writer wishes to evoke in the reader.

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether you treat the creature as one who has an intellect or not. For example, in "Harry Potter and the sorcerer's stone" where goblins were bank workeres, author refers to them as to persons:

"The goblin was about a head shorter than Harry. He had a swarthy, clever face, a pointed beard and, Harry noticed, very long fingers and feet. He bowed as they walked inside."

But other mythical creature, troll, is treated differently:

"The troll stopped next to a doorway and peered inside. It waggled its long ears, making up its tiny mind, then slouched slowly into the room."

Comment: That seems to be a good approach, more or less similar to one proposed by Ian.